# Bootstrap modal remove all padding for mobile version

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Let's say there is a standard modal window.

For screens up to 767px there are standard paddings:

[image]

The question is, how can I remove these indents for such a screen so that the window is full screen?

Comment: Have you tried setting the modal to viewport height and width in css for the screen size you want. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts

Comment: Also its better practice to import js scripts just before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about margin, not padding (padding is the whitespace inside the modal's edge; margin is the grey space outside the modal's edge which prevents it from looking full-screen).

You would think that the logical 'Bootstrap' answer is to apply a class `m-0 m-md-2` to the `modal-dialog` div, however this doesn't work unfortunately.

As a result, apply the following custom class `modal-full-mobile` to the `modal-dialog` div, and add the custom CSS below to your stylesheet:

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-full-mobile">  <!-- Class goes here -->
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    &times;
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                    Modal Header
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Close
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Put this inside a style tag or a CSS file**

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .modal-full-mobile {
        margin: 0px!important;
    }
}
```

---

**Before**
[image: What it looks like before]

**After**
[image: What it looks like now]

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: Are you sure? I've just added a screenshot, it now works on mine perfectly. Have you definitely put the class name in the modal-dialog div? And added the CSS to either a stylesheet or style tag?

Comment: everything works, sorry